# Deliberately causing a program to hang from the command prompt in WIndows 7

Tags: windows-7

Suppose I have an application window. I also know its corresponding process.

I know that this serves pretty much no practical use but, from the command prompt, is it possible to deliberately cause the application to hang ("not responding")?

Comment: On unix-like systems you can send a SIGSTOP signal to a process, which stops it unless it has code to catch the signal.

Comment: SIGSTOP can't be catched, but SIGSTP can. SIGSTP is sent when doing Ctrl+Z on a running process in a shell for example.

Comment: As LPChip mentions, if you know the application "accesses" a certain resource you could remove the resource and it will hang. That is if the original programmer did not put in exception handling to test for existence. Some programmers put in resource checks on application startup, you remove the resource once it is running you can get hangs/crashes/bsod :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not unless that specific application was programmed badly, and you abuse a bug to crash it. It is possible using external tools to suspend a program. The program will be frozen, but windows will not say it is "not responding".

Comment: PsSuspend from Sysinternals for example: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897540.aspx

Comment: "Suspending" isn't the same as a "hang". But of course a "hang" is not the same as "not responding"